# how can i add active class to image slider dynamically in Django template?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

i have an image slider which does not show anything if the  image  does not have active class on it as it slides through a list of images.

```
{% for v in m.value.images %}<div class="carousel-item active"> <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h1>Another example headline.</h1> </div></div>{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Your HTML structure for the slider container -->
   <div class="slider-container">
     {% for v in m.value.images %}
         <img src="{{ v.image_url }}" alt="{{ v.image_alt }}" 
         class="slider-image {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}">
     {% endfor %}
   </div>
```

In this code, the `{% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}` part ensures that the `"active"` class is added only to the first image in the loop. The forloop variable in Django templates provides information about the current iteration of a loop. forloop.first is a boolean that is True for the first iteration of the loop and False for subsequent iterations.

This way, when the page is loaded, the first image in the slider will have the "active" class, and the slider should display something even if the JavaScript is disabled or not used for this specific purpose.

I suggest that you definitely read these articles about forloop in Django template tags in the future.
[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#:~:text=The%20for%20loop%20sets%20a%20number%20of%20variables%20available%20within%20the%20loop%3A](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#:%7E:text=The%20for%20loop%20sets%20a%20number%20of%20variables%20available%20within%20the%20loop%3A)

[https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_tags_for.php#:~:text=Run%20Example%20%C2%BB-,Loop%20Variables,-Django%20has%20some](https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_tags_for.php#:%7E:text=Run%20Example%20%C2%BB-,Loop%20Variables,-Django%20has%20some)

Comment: this solution is good but in my situation can not work. am using  {% image  v.image width-400 %}

Comment: Do you use the template tag to change the size of the images?